# Добавить список в базу при помощи sqlite3 (Python 3)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite3

Есть список **list_rule_1**. В нём каждый элемент '1523617883276-545841109109949563' в виде строки. Всего элементов в списке 403. Хочу добавить этот список в базу с именем **mydb.sqlite** в таблицу **conversions** в столбец **conv_rule**. Какой строчкой кода это сделать? И нужно ли список преобразовать в кортеж?
Вот с чего я начал:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE conversions conv_rule")
conn.commit()
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO conversions VALUES (?)", list_rule_1) #с этого момента неработает
```

Comment: начните со списка с двумя элементами и минимальной таблицы с парой столбцов. Используйте insert/update и executemany(). Если получите неожиданный результат, добавьте в ваш вопрос минимальный пример кода, ввод, ожидаемый вывод и с что вы вместо этого получаете [mcve]

Comment: Пример это хорошо, но он ещё недостаточно самодостаточный. Ответ зависит от того, чем *конкретно* является `list_rule_1` — добавьте его в пример или хотя бы покажите результат его печати в консоль (простым словам вместо кода я предпочитаю не верить :)

Comment: Результат печати в консоль list_rule_1  - http://take.ms/Qw6Ca

Comment: for value in list_rule_1:
    temp_ = tuple([value])
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO conversions VALUES (?)', temp_)
    conn.commit()     Оказывается каждый элемент списка должен быть кортежем и я пока только смог при помощи execute в цикле записать данные в столбец. А можно при помощи executemany сразу все элементы(кортежи) списка записать в нужный столбец.